# Hide/show individual or specific button inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-directive, angular-ngfor

I am new to angular. I am iterating through an array of objects. I have declared two buttons that is Start & End. I want to display the start initially for each item. when user click on Start button of an item that item's start button should hide & End button should display.

```js
 startTask(id) {
    console.log('item id',id)
  }

  EndTask(index) {
    console.log('item id',id)
  }
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="card width hr" *ngFor="let item of allUserTaskArr">
    <div class="card-header">
      {{item.due | date}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pad-125">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{item.name}}
          <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-info mar-l-r-0-5" (click)="startTask(item.id)">Start</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger mar-l-r-0-5" (click)="EndTask(item.id)">End</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, each item has a unique ID. for each item there is one start & end button. I want to display the start button initially for all & when I click on the Start button of an item only that button should replace with End button. all others should remain the same.

[![ngFor items image]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pvLE.png

Comment: Are you tracking ON/OFF in any variable?

Comment: I have used a flag variable & toggle that variable on button click. but it changes all buttons state.

Comment: Here is the stackbitz url
please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvj3cd

Comment: thank you, but when I refresh the page the state of the button is changed to default. I am getting the object from the server there is no start & end flag in the response.

Comment: you can set a start and end flag on the client side after you get the response from the server

Answer (score 1):

first you need extra property like button of that array

.ts file

```
allUserTaskArr = [
    {
      'name': 'abc',
      'id':1,
      'button': 'start',
    },
     {
      'name': 'xyz',
      'id':1,
      'button': 'end',
    }
  ];
 public startTask (item) {
   item.button =  'end';
 }

 public endTask (item) {
   item.button =  'start';
 }
```

and .html file is

```
<div class="card width hr" *ngFor="let item of allUserTaskArr">
    <div class="card-header">
      {{item.due | date}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pad-125">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{item.name}}
          <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-info mar-l-r-0-5" *ngIf="item.button =='start'" (click)="startTask(item)">Start</button>
            <button  (click)="endTask(item)" class="btn btn-danger mar-l-r-0-5" *ngIf="item.button =='end'">End</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**another way**
Button change by index
.html file

```
 <div class="card width hr" *ngFor="let item of allUserTaskArr; let i = index">
    <div class="card-header">
      {{item.due | date}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pad-125">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{item.name}}
          <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-info mar-l-r-0-5" *ngIf="item.button =='start'" (click)="startTask(item, i)">Start</button>
            <button  (click)="endTask(item, i)" class="btn btn-danger mar-l-r-0-5" *ngIf="item.button =='end'">End</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.ts file

```
 allUserTaskArr = [
    {
      'name': 'abc',
      'id':1,
      'button': 'start',
    },
     {
      'name': 'xyz',
      'id':1,
      'button': 'end',
    }
  ];
 public startTask (item, index) {
   this.allUserTaskArr[index].button = 'end';
 }

 public endTask (item, index) {
   this.allUserTaskArr[index].button =  'start';
 }
```